# Did the Force help Luke Skywalker in hitting the core of the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, a-new-hope, death-star

I was wondering if the Force helped Luke Skywalker in hitting the core of the Death Star?

Comment: Did you miss the part where a mysterious voice said,"Use the Force, Luke"?

Comment: Just because it's not a very *good* question (no offense), doesn't mean that it should be deleted. It's still on topic, @ whoever flagged it.

Comment: @Mithrandir That's why I answered it :)  Surprisingly, I couldn't find it having been answered before.

Comment: @JaneS yeah, it's just slightly ridiculous that it was flagged *twice*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's almost certain that Luke used the Force to destroy the Death Star

If you recall the scene, he had the targeting computer aligned, but was implored by Obi-Wan to trust in the Force.  So he switched off the targeting computer, and allowed himself to be guided as to when to release his torpedoes.

Also recall that there was another near miss on the port by another more experienced pilot who *was* using the targeting computer.  The defining difference was Luke's growing affinity with the Force.  So while it *could* have been pure, dumb luck, that's highly unlikely.

Here's the scene to remind you :)

Comment: Is this... tvRip? Wow.

Comment: @JanDvorak I have no idea, I just hit Youtube for "Star Wars destroy Death Star" and this is the first one I got :)

Answer (score 6):

While this answer isn't canon, it actually uses the canon entirely for its argument. It is addressed directly in this video, but the answer boils down to: yes, it was literally the only way it could have been done. (Warning: NSFW language in video)

The video points out that the missiles had to be fired under combat conditions, into a port the size of a whomp-rat, make a 90 degree turn, travel completely straight down a small corridor the length of the radius of a moon, all while reminding you that this is an *exhaust* port which means the heat of the entire Death Star engine was being forcefully pumped opposite to the direction of the missiles. It is scientifically completely impossible for this to happen. But it did nonetheless. How? Magic space wizards.

Oh, but all the magic space wizards are dead. Right, except for one small farm kid named *Skywalker* who just so happens to be the son of the legendary Annakin Skywalker who disappeared just around the time the terrifying Lord Vader with his terrifying mastery of the Force appeared. Maybe had someone *told* the engineer involved in the design to take *magic space wizards* into account in his design, he could have. The design makes it scientifically impossible for missiles to hit. If you're going to tell an engineer that magic need not be a concern, that engineer will design something as such.

Comment: While humorous, the video misses the fact that the torpedoes are self-propelled, possess guidance systems and maneuvering thrusters, and could have been stopped with a multi-stage exhaust system with some FOD detectors. In reality, a modern fighter jet could have made the shot from a hundred miles away if we gave the missile a way to slow down for the 90° turn just after entry. And ignore the fact that fighter jets can't operate in a vacuum, of course. Given enough fuel, they could have made the shot *from Yavin 4*, and those turbo-lasers would have never seen it coming.

Comment: "If we gave the middle a way to slow down for the 90 degree turn" right, pesky physics gets in the way again.

Comment: @MichaelS "And ignore the fact that fighter jets can't operate in a vacuum, of course." Because of course Star Wars pays such deep attention to the laws of physics and basic common sense. ;)

Comment: Isn't there something about a chain reaction in the briefing room? The torpedo doesn't have to travel all the way in.

Comment: @Gusdor Yes, exactly that.

Comment: One thing the video does not get into: Any attack by *big* ships would have been shredded by the turbolasers. And even for the fighters, it was a suicide run to even attempt. (How many got shot down for the *two* actual launches at the target?) It took a *very* desperate, capable, **and** lucky attacker to succeed at this. Will a [Ticonderoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticonderoga-class_cruiser) shoot down basically any approaching air threat with ease? Yes. Can it *guarantee* that not a single attacker will make it to target? Of course not. So take it easy on that engineer, will ya? :-D

Comment: The video also misses that the Rebels *didn't know* that Luke was a space wizard. The mission strategists thought it was at least semi-reasonable for a regular pilot with a standard layout to be able to do the shot!

Comment: @CTMacUser wait, what? I'm not going to pretend to be an expert on the films, but didn't he show up with Obi Wan and being trained in the Force? Han Solo would never have made a joke about the old man training him in the ways of an archaic religion instead of use of Blasters? Leia would have been completely silent on the subject?

Comment: @Broklynite, Luke didn't show up with Kenobi, because the latter was killed by Vader. Leia didn't know Luke was a Jedi apprentice, Han and Chewbacca weren't staying, and Luke didn't seem to request special treatment. The mission wasn't to protect Luke to use his space-wizard powers, but for anyone who got close enough to take the shot.